# Entity Framework 6 table splitting generates an invalid migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using EF table splitting with code-firat in our project so we can improve the performance of the database (one of our models contains 127 columns). The splitting is working fine if we use it with lazy loading or with queries but we encounter a problem when we want to access the splitted models as a table (dbContext.UserSettings.FindAsync(userId)). When adding the models as tables to the DbContext we get an invalid migration.

I'm not sure if we encounterd a bug or we just made a configuration error. I have created a minimal example to reproduce the error.

**Conditions**

- The model must be split in at least 2 splitted models
- The model must contain at least 2 relations with another model

**The problem**

A DbContext without the splitted models defined as tables generates a correct Migration. The relations are correct and all the models are present and working. When we add the table definition for the splitted models EF generates a migration that swaps the columns of the two zero-to-many relations and breaking the database and code.

```
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Users", name: "ImageLargeId", newName: "__mig_tmp__0");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Users", name: "ImageSmallId", newName: "ImageLargeId");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Users", name: "__mig_tmp__0", newName: "ImageSmallId");
RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Users", name: "IX_ImageLargeId", newName: "__mig_tmp__0");
RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Users", name: "IX_ImageSmallId", newName: "IX_ImageLargeId");
RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Users", name: "__mig_tmp__0", newName: "IX_ImageSmallId");
```

This of course will break our database and code. We have tried different approaches but it will always result in this invalid migration.

**Code**

```
public class BugContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    // BUG: Enable/disable this part will generate a invalid migration file
    //public virtual DbSet<UserSettings> UserSettings { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<UserRights> UserRights { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSettings>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRights>().ToTable("Users");

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(user => user.ImageSmall).WithMany(image => image.User_ImageSmalls);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(user => user.ImageLarge).WithMany(image => image.User_ImageLarges);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(user => user.Settings).WithRequiredPrincipal(userSettings => userSettings.User);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(user => user.Rights).WithRequiredPrincipal(userRights => userRights.User);
    }
}

public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> User_ImageSmalls { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User_ImageLarges { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? ImageSmallId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image ImageSmall { get; set; }

    public Guid? ImageLargeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image ImageLarge { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSettings Settings { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRights Rights { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool DarkTheme { get; set; }
}

public class UserRights
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool Admin { get; set; }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Add a migration: "add-migration Init"
2. Update the database: "update-database"
3. Uncomment the following code "public virtual DbSet UserSettings { get; set; }" and "public virtual DbSet UserRights { get; set; }"
4. Add a migration: "add-migration Bug"

Comment: I don't understand why you would even try to do this. If you want 3 tables, then have 3 tables. An entity should really match the table definition as closely as possible. If you want to only retrieve a select few columns, then create queries that do that.

Comment: When changing the properties you need the full model (slow) or you have to manual set the properties to updated and attach it to the DbContext (a lot of work). This is a solution to lazy load properties of the model you don't often use/update. We don't want to use different tables for one-to-one relations (is this even supported?) because the columns all belongs to the same model and now we can freely move the properties between the models. A suggestion for a different approach is more than welcome because this is blocking you Core.NET migration.

Comment: So why not manually set the properties? That's pretty simple, you could even use reflection to simplify that code.